# How filter object values with es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

i have a 2 object which i wan't to make filtering with es6

first is my data object and second selected some data.

I wan't to get all items in data object which have second object values

```
let data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'A',
    status: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'B',
    status: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'C',
    status: 3
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'D',
    status: 2
  }
]
```

and second object is :

```
let selectedStatus = [
  {
    id: 1,
    status: 1
  },
  {
    status: 3
  }
]
```

in this case i want't to get data object items which contains same statuses in second object so in this case i need to get this result:

```
data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'A',
    status: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'B',
    status: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'C',
    status: 3
  },
]
```

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: How have you tried it so far, what have you attempted?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: What is it you want to do with `selectedStatus[0].id`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
data = data.filter(item =>
  selectedStatus.map(s => s.status).includes(item.status)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let result = [];    
selectedStatus.forEach(selectedStatus => result = result.concat(data.filter(status => status.status === selectedStatus.status)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet will give the expected answer:

```
var result = [];
data.forEach((value) => {
    selectedStatus.forEach(val => {
        if(value.status == val.status) { 
            result.push(value) 
        } 
    }); 
});
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not have any browser restrictions, you can make use of followed by using [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check statuses on `data` which are on `selectedStatus`, followed by [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out objects which match the required condition.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'A',
    status: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'B',
    status: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'C',
    status: 3
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'D',
    status: 2
  }
]

const selectedStatus = [
  {
    id: 1,
    status: 1
  },
  {
    status: 3
  }
];

const res = data.filter(obj => selectedStatus.map(s => s.status).includes(obj.status));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a third list, like your expected result, you can generate a white-list to match against.

```
const whiteList = selectedStatus.map((sel) => sel.status); // which gives you an array of all selected status you want to filter for

const filteredData = data.filter((data) => ~whiteList.indexOf(data.status)); // please consider that filter returns a new array that contain all items where the condition was falsy. That can be confusing.
```

to understand the `~` operator please check
https://wsvincent.com/javascript-tilde/

you may struggle with the result of the filtered array. Please consider that `array.filter` returns a new array that contain all items which did NOT met the condition in other words its a negation. That can be confusing.
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

ES7

```
const filteredData = data.filter((data) => whiteList.includes(data.status));
```

Comment: You could use includes or some instead of using the ~ with indexOf.

Comment: Yes its a more simple solution but requires ES7, he asked for an ES6 solution...

Comment: Some is [es6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Specifications) but question is also marked React and that doesn't do anything without babel anyway (because of the jsx). Maybe OP added es6 thinking it's the latest since it was such a buzzword a while ago.